# Добавление текста в видео (AVI) с последующим сохранением

Tags: c#, видео, avi

Есть видеофайл с записью движения объекта. Есть данные о его скорости (средняя скорость, пока). В видео картинку надо добавить вычисленное значение пройденного пути.

Какие пути решения этой задачи на c#?

Comment: Уточните, вы хотите сделать водяной знак или именно субтитры, которые можно приложить в виде отдельного текстового файла или включить в виде канала в видеофайле.

Comment: @Bulson, я бы рассмотрел оба варианта.

Comment: дайте две, понятно, но лучше уж выбрать что-то одно.

Comment: @Bulson, В идеале текст в видео, без подключений внешних файлов. Насчитал время, нарисовал на картинку, сохранил в файл.

Comment: Видимо, придется воспользоваться [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: В качестве альтернативного решения могу посоветовать сконвертировать значения пройденого пути в субтитры и добавить к видео при помощи того-же ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Без C#.

Можно сделать субтитры в программе AegiSub в том числе оформить дизайн и положение в пространстве с помощью ASSDRaw3 идущим в комплекте.

Потом с помощью видеоредактора вшить субтитры как хардсаб.(Без отдельного файла, не отключаемые).
Удобен Xilisoft Video Converter.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `Video Converter for .NET` - https://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx